# Removing a tag does not immediately remove the question from the list of questions for the tag

Tags: bug, search, retagging

I just removed the [geometric-probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometric-probability) tag from [Coupon collector problem with a large set of coupons](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4876484). When I then searched for questions with this tag (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometric-probability), I got this list:

[image: list of questions tagged with geometric-probability]

The question still appeared there, but without the tag. A couple of minutes later, it no longer appeared in the list.

If the question had still appeared with the tag, I wouldn’t have thought much of it – probably the database change just hadn’t propagated to the server answering my search query yet. But apparently the server already knew that the question no longer had the tag but was still including it in the list.

It’s obviously not a big problem, and it quickly resolved itself, so no need for action if it can’t be fixed easily, but I thought I’d report it in case it can.

Comment: "Tags are cached for searches and a post may still show up in a tag search after the tag is edited out" - according to this: [What is caching, and where is it used?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/178597) The post is 10 years old, so one cannot take for granted that it is up-to-date.  If you look at the [questions linked there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/178596), you can probably find some posts related to the same issue.